# Approximate diagonalization of hermitian matrices subject to certain constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-transformations, diagonalization, hermitian-matrices

Given a Hermitian matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we can use Schur decomposition to diagonalize it:

\begin{equation}
U^*XU=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 &  & \\ & \ddots &  \\   &    &\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

What if the diagonal elements after the transformation are subject to certain upper bound? Then we can try to diagonalize $X$ as much as possible to satisfy the constraint. But we need some proper measure of the deviation from diagonality. Maybe the sum of squares of the off-diagonal elements? Let $T=T_\text{diag}+T_\text{off}$, where

\begin{equation}
T_\text{diag}=\begin{bmatrix}t_{11} &  &  &\\&t_{22}&&\\& & \ddots &  \\  & &    &0\end{bmatrix},\quad T_\text{off}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & t_{12} & \ldots & t_{1n}\\t_{21}&0&\ldots&t_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\t_{n1}  &t_{n2} &  \ldots  &t_{nn}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Then the sum of squares of off-diagonal elements in $T$ is the square of the Frobenious norm of $T_\text{off}$.

Then, we formulate the following optimization problem:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & ||T_\text{off}||_F\\U\in\mathcal{U}\\\text{subject to} & U^*XU=T=T_\text{diag}+T_\text{off}\\&T_{ii}\leq a_{ii},\end{array}

where $||T_\text{off}||_F$ is the Frobenious norm of $T_\text{off}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is the set of all $n\times n$ unitary matrices. I am wondering if we can get a closed-form solution?

Comment: Isn't the trace known exactly? $tr(X)=tr(T_{diag})=\sum\lambda_i$?

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen but what if we have a constraint that after the transformation the trace of T must be less than certain amount which is not equal to sum of eigenvalues

Comment: @Lee even after the transformation, $T = U^*XU$ will have exactly the same trace as $X$ no matter what your choice of (unitary) $U$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have edited the question. Thanks, initial formulation was not correct

Comment: I suspect that something interesting can be said using the Schur-Horn theorem

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, I found this theorem before, it is useful to see the feasible region.

Comment: I suspect that you always minimize the error by taking $T_{ii} = a_{ii}$

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for indices as in $T_\text{off}$ using `T_\text{off}`.